# Ruby retrieve data from file after specific label

Tags: ruby

How can I get specific data from a file in ruby? I want to get some 10. ip addresses from a file set up like this...

```
Whatever:     xathun
ip_address:   10.2.232.6
etc:          aouoeu
more:         snthuh
```

I want to push the ip addresses into an array.

I can pull 10. addresses out of text. I was hoping for a more accurate way to do it as in only the data after the 'ip_address:' label in case there is unwanted matching data.

Answer (score 1):

```
s_text = File.open("test.txt",'r').read
ip_addresses = s_text.scan(/\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+/)
puts ip_addresses.inspect #=> ["10.2.232.6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple enough solution.

```
open('<textfile path>') { |f| puts f.grep(/10\./) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is setup like that throughout you can do:

```
arr = []
File.open("text").each_line do |line|
  parts = line.split(":")
  arr << parts[1].strip if parts[0] == "ip_address"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to array as you go through once, one line at a time:
**ip_data.txt**

```
Whatever:     xathun
ip_address:   10.2.232.6   
etc:          aouoeu
more:         snthuh

Whatever:     badone
ip_address:   66.8.103.3    
etc:          huh
more:         noooo

Whatever:     blah
ip_address:   10.9.244.13    
etc:          hello
more:         goodbye
```

**code**

```
found_tens = []
File.open('ip_data.txt') {|f|
  f.each {|line|
    line = line.chomp
    next if line.empty?
    found_tens << $1 if line =~ /^ip_address:\s+(10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/
  }
}
p found_tens  #["10.2.232.6", "10.9.244.13"]
```